# Android: SqlLiteDatabase delete does not work for certain ID

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a very strange bug in my code. Add/Remove to SqlLiteDb works well. But there is one entry I can't remove. I really have no idea how this is possible.

I add a value like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_ID, id);
getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_SUBSCRIPTIONS, null, values);
```

And remove a value like this:

```
getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_SUBSCRIPTIONS, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
```

If I call

```
addEntry("43.05071");
removeEntry("43.05071");
```

the db is empty.

But after

```
addEntry("43.06600");
removeEntry("43.06600");
```

43.06600 is still in the db.

When I execute

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_SUBSCRIPTIONS)
```

the table is empty as expected even if it contained 43.06600.

I doubt that the ID per se causes the problem. But do you have any ideas what I could have overlooked?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I updated my remote database and changed the id from 43.06600 to 43.05072. No it works for the object which had the 43.06600 id. How is that possible?

Comment: How is the id field defined? Is it an integer?

Comment: @DerGolem No a string. I create the database with: "create table " + TABLE_SUBSCRIPTIONS + "(" + COLUMN_ID +  " text primary key not null);"

Comment: If so, you must add the **'** around the id, since it is a string. `"delete from "+ TABLE_SUBSCRIPTIONS` deletes the whole table, without the id comparison. That's why it works.

Comment: @DerGolem Yes now it works! Thank you so much. Do you have an explaination why it worked for some ids but not for all?

Comment: I guess the 43.06600 was interpreted as a real number and you saw rounding effects.